# Por qué mi aplicación android deja de recibir datos después de un tiempo?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

Buen día.

Estoy enviando datos por bluetooth de un dispositivo medico desde una tarjeta arduino hacia un app, el codigo del dispositivo medico de arduino es el siguiente:

```html
#include <eHealth.h>
  float datosECG[200], ImprimeDatosECG[100]; 
  float PosPar;
  int pos,i,cont=0;
  

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  
if(eHealth.getECG()>0.5)
{
  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    pos=i;
    datosECG[i] = eHealth.getECG();
    PosPar = pos%50;
    
    if(PosPar==0)
    {
                    Serial.print('#'); 
                    Serial.println("ecg"); 
        Serial.println(datosECG[i]);
                    Serial.print("\n");
                    Serial.print('~');
                    Serial.print("\n");        
    }
  }
  delay(1); // wait for a millisecond
}

}
```

Esta es la clase donde leo el flujo de entrada

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private DataParse mDataParse;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        int bytes;
        mDataParse = new DataParse(mHandler);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Mientras se mantenga la conexion el hilo se mantiene en espera ocupada
        // leyendo del flujo de entrada
        while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // Leemos del flujo de entrada del socket
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                //byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                mDataParse.Add(buffer, bytes);

                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                                    mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MSG_LEER,bytes,-1,readMessage).sendToTarget();

                //System.out.println("Bytes: "+bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            }

           /* try {
                Thread.sleep(40);//originalmente estaba en 40
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                                //(Message.what (int),Message.arg1 (int),Message.arg2 (int), Message.obj  (byte[]))
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Una vez establecida la conexión entre el app y el arduino el app empieza a recibir datos, estos se reciben a una velocidad normal, pero conforme avanza el tiempo la velocidad de transferencia va disminuyendo hasta terminar por ya no recibir datos.
Este es el Handler dentro de la clase MainActivity donde hago la lectura de las cadenas que envío desde el arduino.

```
    // Handler que obtendrá informacion de BluetoothChatServiceService y otros hilos que invoquen el método obtainMessage() del handler
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private Handler mMainHandler = new Handler()    {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        byte[] buffer   = null;
        String mensaje  = null;
        //int endOfLineIndex;

        switch (msg.what) {

            case CONST.MSG_LEER:
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                recDataString.append(readMessage);                                   
                int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                    String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                    int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();                          //get length of data received
                    System.out.println("Inicio de linea: "+recDataString.charAt(0));
                    System.out.println("completa: "+recDataString.substring(0,endOfLineIndex));
                    try {
                        dispositivo = (recDataString.charAt(1) + "" + recDataString.charAt(2) + "" + recDataString.charAt(3) + "");
                    }catch (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){System.out.println("Error de inicio de linea");}
                    System.out.println("DISPOSITIVO: "+dispositivo);

                    if(recDataString.charAt(0)=='#')
                    {
                        switch (dispositivo) {

                            case "ecg":
                                string_ecg = recDataString.substring(6,10);
                                System.out.println("ecg: "+string_ecg);
                                fecg = Float.parseFloat(string_ecg);
                                String strecg = Float.toString(fecg);
                                Globals.lstSendECGData3.add(strecg);
                                System.out.println("ECG data: "+strecg);

                                ServiceManager.onSendData();
                                break;

                            default:
                                System.out.println("No esta entrando");
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                }

                break;

        }
    }
};

introducir el código aquí
```

No tengo mucha experiencia trabajando con bluetooth y desconozco que es lo que esta pasando, si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Hola @Xavi sería bueno que coloques el código de la app(solo la parte de la comunicación) ya que como esta tu pregunta es imposible resolverla

Comment: Revisa si no es por que estas ejecutandolo en el hilo principal del activity, mientras esperas esos 20 segundos mueve siempre tu dedo, para ver si se prolonga más tiempo.

Comment: Buen día @eyllanesc , antes que nada gracias por responder, he re formulado la pregunta pues carecía de mucha información para ser resuelta, espero que a como la he puesto sea mas entendible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen dia, el problema era que estaba definiendo la cadena donde guardaba el mensaje  leido (recDataString) como variable global, al cambiarla por una variable local dentro del handler se solucionó el problema. Saludos